# Apache mod proxy does use a different charset then proxied server

Tags: apache-httpd, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I'm running jenkins, a java web application, on port 8080 behind an apache2 server using mod_proxy.

```
+---------------+              +----------------+
|    apache2    |    ----->    |  jenkins:8080  |    
+---------------+              +----------------+
```

When I access jenkins directly e.g. http://myhost:8080/ the result looks normal (All characters are encoded correct).

[image: jenkins direct access]

But when I try it through the apache proxy it looks like this

[image: jenkins behind apache2 mod proxy]

My mod_proxy configuration is

```
SSLEngine on

ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

SetOutputFilter proxy-html
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE

SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

Header edit Location ^http://myhost/ https://myhost/
```

My language settings are

```
# echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
# echo $LC_ALL
en_US.utf8
```

Does anyone know how to keep the correct charset?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem following the [jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache)

I ensured that all mods are enabled

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod headers
```

and used this configuration

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8081/jenkins nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8081/jenkins
ProxyRequests     Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# Local reverse proxy authorization override
# Most unix distribution deny proxy by default (ie /etc/apache2/modsenabled/proxy.conf in Ubuntu)
<Proxy http://localhost:8081/jenkins*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Maybe the configuration I posted in my question contains some error. I used it because it was already present on the old server. I moved jenkins to a new server.